# MVC - Openning a web page with POST parameters

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, angular-ui-router, asp.net-mvc-routing

I currently have an angular app which contains 2 pages.

When the user finishes with page1, I create a variable with some data he entered on that page and put it in the main controller (a controller above the 2 pages). Then the state changes (he get redirected to page2) and page2 reads the data from the main controller.

Now I want to split the 2 pages into 2 diffirent web sites with diffirent addresses. How can I open page2 from page1 with parameters (GET is not an option, the data is more then what is allowed for url).

NOTE : Both pages are written in angular and page2 is currently not in MVC - its just simple HTML, css and js files. But if someone has a solution involving minimal MVC - its great.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it trough a hidden form. It will submit your data as POST whatever the target url is

Comment: It will send the data to the server side of page2 which I don't have. My problem is not sending the data from page1, It's creating a minimal server side for page2 which can accept the parameters and send it to the view

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you can do that

Completely client side solution

1. Using cookies / local storage - i have been using [angular storage library](https://github.com/auth0/angular-storage) to perform exactly what you are trying to do. *This solution will **not** work if you are putting the pages on 2 different domains*. As the cookies and localstorage can only be read by the domain they are created by.

Solutions requiring to save the state on server side and then accessing them on the second page.

2. Its easy to use sessions / temporary sessions to storage data server side.
3. Using a third party state storage is also possible ex. Firebase.

Solutions not requiring you to save the state at all but require you to handle POST data on the server side

4. Make a hidden form on page1. With action attribute pointing to the url of the page2. Keep the data inside form using ng-model etc. when you are ready to make the transition POST / Submit the form. Handle the POST data on the second website / url and inject it into the second page